# Jquery Sliding Side Menu Solutions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I need a sliding / side menu, replicating the one on the right hand side [here](https://trello.com/b/nNk2Yq1k/ionic-framework) without using the ionic framework.

The positioning and height is what I need, and fact it overlays other content and doesn't have any sort of fading effect as seen on [blivesta](http://git.blivesta.com/drawer).

Any links to an existing sidebar would be appreciated.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple css for that effect, something like this,

```
HTML
<nav></nav>

CSS
nav {
    background:#ccc; 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -50%;
    z-index: 9;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .3s; 
            transition-duration: .3s;
}

nav.open {
    right: 0;
}
```

and then use some jquery to toggle the click

```
$('nav').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('open')) {
        $this.removeClass('open');
    }else{
        $this.addClass('open');
    }
});
```

see if that helps ;)